# Dynamic url of a jsonstore

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a store as follows:

```
s_store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
                    .........,
                    fields: specord
                    });
```

I need to set the url dynamically based on a condition - something like below:

```
var dyn_url=(this.isProposal==false)?'......':'.........';
s_store.setUrl(dyn_url);
```

I have not many been able to find anything that allows this - am on ExtJs3.3.
Is there any way this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

JsonStore has a setProxy method, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonStore-method-setProxy

```
myStore.setProxy({
    type: 'ajax',
    url : '/my-new-url'
});
```

That should be enough for you to set the url dyncamically.

Or you can also try...

```
myStore.getProxy().url = "http://my-new-url"
mystore.load()
```

Comment: can you post the rest of the code you're using for the JsonStore? Or at least the proxy